# Best Practice for RESTful API Relationships, Endpoints, and Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

Let's say I have different models in my application: Venue, Guest, Reservation, Purchases, Tables. What's the "correct" way to nest these relationships? Such as...

- A venue has many guests, through a reservation
- A guest has many purchases at a venue, through a reservation
- A reservation has many guests
- A venue has many reservations
- A venue has many tables

... and so forth.

Should I (with standard, RESTful CRUD)...

```
/api/venues/{venue_id}/reservations
/api/venues/{venue_id}/reservations/{reservation_id}/purchases
/api/venues/{venue_id}/reservations/{reservation_id}/guests 
/api/venues/{venue_id}/tables
```

or should reservations, purchases, and guests all be in a separate resource? Such as,

```
/api/reservations
/api/tables
```

And accept parameters such as guest_id, item_id (for purchase), table_id (for a table), and etc...

What should I do if I want to view a single resource within a relation?

I realize that there's no "hard rules" to this, but in the long-term, what's the best practice to take? Why?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question. As written, your post here is very broad and opinion-based, and could be considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be one and only one way to get the data from API.
So you choose one approach or another.

Let's consider `guests`:

if you'll go for

```
/api/venues/{venue_id}/reservations/{reservation_id}/guests
```

each time we need to get a reservation guests, the `venue_id` is
required. Even more, when we need to get a specific guest

```
/api/venues/{venue_id}/reservations/{reservation_id}/guests/{guest_id}
```

the `venue_id` AND `reservation_id` are both required.

Is that strictly necessary? Well, for the sake of authorization maybe it
is. But the

```
/api/guests/{guest_id}
```

is more "safe" and flexible approach, which can require or not require
`venue_id` or `reservation_id` in specific cases.